# Need to have subquery within subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have a `stock` table which holds for example

```
 Partnumber | Depot | flag_redundant
------------+-------+----------------
          1 |     1 |              5
          1 |     2 |              0
          1 |     3 |              0              
          1 |     4 |              5
          2 |     1 |              0
          2 |     2 |              0
          2 |     3 |              0
          2 |     4 |              0
```

I need to be able to see the depots in which the parts have not been flagged as redundant, but the `flag_redundant` has been at least been flagged once for that part, and I need to ignore any parts where there has not been a flag flagged.

Any help appreciated!

I'm thinking of something along the lines of ....

```
SELECT stock.part, stock.depot, 
       OrderCount = (SELECT CASE WHEN Stock.flag_redundant = 5 THEN 1 end as Countcolumn FROM stock C)
  FROM stock 

 Partnumber | MissingDepots
------------+---------------
          1 | Yes
```

Comment: I tried to format your question to the best of my abilities, but the description of the desired query result is still lacking. Please improve it! Try to use simple sentences, particularly if you don't write English well.

Comment: Can you explain why partnumber = 1 satisfies the conditions?

Comment: Thanks guys...part number = 1 is an example of a part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by partnumber and set the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
select 
  partnumber, 'Yes' MissingDepots 
from stock 
group by partnumber
having 
  sum(flag_redundant) > 0 and 
  sum(case when flag_redundant = 0 then 1 end) > 0
```

Or:

```
select 
  partnumber, 'Yes' MissingDepots 
from stock 
group by partnumber
having sum(case when flag_redundant = 0 then 1 end) between 1 and count(*) - 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=c6389ce4c408f079f973d75ef16775ec).
 
Results:

```
> partnumber | missingdepots
> ---------: | :------------
>          1 | Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get these `partnumber`s that contain data sets with `flag_redundant` = `5` AND `0`:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d4971b6398684914ea8a7b85b6f15bbe)

```
 SELECT 
    partnumber,
    'Yes' AS missing
FROM (
    SELECT
        partnumber,
        COUNT(flag_redundant) FILTER (WHERE flag_redundant = 5) AS cnt_redundant,   -- 2
        COUNT(*) AS cnt                                                             -- 3
    FROM
       stock
    GROUP BY partnumber                                                             -- 1
) s
WHERE cnt_redundant > 0                                                             -- 4
   AND cnt_redundant < cnt                                                          -- 5
```

1. Group by `partnumber`
2. Count all records with `flag_redundant` = 5
3. Count all records
4. Find all `partnumber`s that contain any element with 5 ...
5. ... and which have more records than 5-element records

Comment: Hi Sman the error I am getting is

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 7:         COUNT(flag_redundant) FILTER (WHERE flag_redundant =...
                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 121

Comment: Which database version are you on?

Comment: It seem that was added in postgres 9.4 we are on 9.1

Comment: You really should update your database! Here is a version which should work. But now this is really close to @forpas version: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=92b4b2f95d72713a91ace9d121785e24

Comment: Thanks.. how do i set it as an answer?